# track how many numbers and counter in array

Tags: java, arrays, counter

I need to find how many votes each one has. I have a count that counted how many candidates there are in play which was 5. And now I have a bunch of numbers from the arraylist that I need to count happy voted each candidate and the number of candidates changes depending on which arraylist I use but for test purposes I am using test5 which has 5.

```
 //Numbers from arraylist:
1
1
2
5
2
5
5
5
```

this is my code

```
// My code
for (int i=1; i <output.size(); i++){
        char checkBallot = output.get(i).charAt(1); 
        //candidate is array to track how many output as what 
                    // output is array of numbers I want to count. 
        String aString = Character.toString(checkBallot);
        int c = Integer.parseInt(aString);
        int b = c; 
        for (int p= 0; p < count; p++){
            if(c == p+1){
                int oldvalue =0; 
                candidate[c] = c+ oldvalue ;
                oldvalue = c ;
                System.out.println("this is the counter:" +c);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Also, paste in the rest of your code... what is output? state? candidate? etc

Comment: output is the numbers from array list state is where in the order it is state for now is one. And candidate is an array to track how many of 1 2 3 4 5 there are in the output. Sorry I am horrible at writing what I want to achieve.

Comment: @ oli I want to count how many 1,2,3,4,5 are there in the output arraylist. And store the amount of each into candidate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should get rid of `oldvalue` and use `++candidate[c];` instead of those three lines. Assuming I understand your code, and I barely do.

Answer (score 0):

To count how many 1,2,3,4,5 are there in the output arraylist: if you have an ArrayList of integers:

```
final int[] candidate = new int[count];
for(int i : output)
    candidate[i]++;
```

assuming that "count" is the greatest value that you may find in the ArrayList.

Instead, if you have an ArrayList of strings, then you write

```
final int[] candidate = new int[count];
for(String i : output)
    candidate[Integer.parseInt(i)]++;
```